# Optional variable force unwrapping that I haven't seen a solutions for

Tags: swift, option-type

Force unwrapping is evil so I'm using guard or if let where I can, but sometimes this is really giving me a headache.

**1 based list index variable to 0 based array in a function**

```
//index is an integer from a 1 based list, so it can be 1, 2, 3,... (index is coming from an external API)
func someFunction (index : Int?) {
guard let newIndex = index - 1 else {
            throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest,
                               message: "blah blah")
        }
 let result = myArray[newIndex]
 ....
}
```

The editor flags an error "

> Value of optional type Int is not unwrapped, did you mean to use ! or
>   ?"

@ index in the line : *guard let newIndex = index - 1 else {*

Adding a ! to index results in another error :

> "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not int"

So the solution I'm currently using is :

```
 guard var newIndex = index else {
            throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest,
                               message: "blah blah")
        }

     newIndex -= 1
     let result = myArray[newIndex]
     ....
```

It works but I think it's kinda ugly coding...

Comment: Please only post 1 question at a time. Each question deserves its own focus and replies.

Comment: ok will do next time, but both questions where related to the same/similar problem so in this case I thought it was ok

Comment: Why next time? Edit out the 2nd question here and post it as a separate question. The existing answers here can be updated as needed.

Comment: it was for the answers, but since you want this I'll update it

Comment: Now hopefully all of the people that down voted will come back and retract their vote.

Comment: are they notified ?

Comment: Instead of waste your brain time to solve null/nil/optional problems you should think about removing them completely from code. It will make your life much easier. I know it, because in my code there is no more null/nil/optional  (except inside of adapter classes for other frameworks). For more informations you may read this article: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/13/why-null-is-bad.html

Comment: @codealchimist Using Optionals properly *is* an excellent way to avoid null issues. It's made for this very purpose.

Comment: @eric-aya If you say so. I only tell you that my code do not contain any optionals anymore and is much easier than before. I don't need 'if let', 'if x != nil', 'guard ...' statements and that made my code much easier to understand and maintain. It's definitely worth thinking about it. Note: I choose the fail early solution described in the blog post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a method invocation rather than an operator for subtraction:

```
func someFunction (index : Int?) {
    guard var newIndex = index?.advanced(by: -1) else {
        throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest,
                           message: "blah blah")
    }

    let result = myArray[newIndex]
    ....
}
```

Which does not answer the question in general, but in your specific case.

Comment: FYI - the question has been updated to be split into two separate questions. You should update your answer accordingly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683509/optional-variable-in-class-definition to post the 2nd half of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let newIndex = index - 1
```

`guard let` is only used for unwrapping an `Optional`. Here, you are confusing the action of unwrapping, and the action of removing 1 to your integer.

You were correct to do that in two steps, not one. And it is not ugly at all!
For example :

```
func someFunction (index : Int?) throws {
    guard let unwrappedIndex = index else {
        //The given index is nil, abort.
        throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest,
                          message: "Index is nil")
    }

    //Now everything is fine, unwrappedIndex is not an Optional anymore.
    guard unwrappedIndex - 1 > 0 else {
        throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest,
                          message: "Wrong index")
    }

    //Happy scenario... Do you things...
    let result = myArray[newIndex]
    ...
}
```

And even better, you are not forced to declare another variable name to unwrap it! Just do a guard like :

```
guard let index = index else { throw Error }
```

Comment: FYI - the question has been updated to be split into two separate questions. You should update your answer accordingly.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683509/optional-variable-in-class-definition to post the 2nd answer.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to use optional binding to unwrap the index and then check if the (1-based) index is in the range of the number of items in the array (~= is the pattern matching operator)

```
guard var newIndex = index, // unwraps the optional
    1...myArray.count ~= newIndex // is index in the range 1 ... number of items in the array
        else {
            throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest,
                           message: "blah blah")
            return }
newIndex -= 1
let result = myArray[newIndex]
```

The valid index range is

```
0-based : 0..<myArray.count
1-based : 1...myArray.count
```

If the check succeeds decrement the index and get the item.

---

Or still simpler if `newIndex` is not used later:

```
guard let newIndex = index, // unwraps the optional
    1...myArray.count ~= newIndex // is index in the range 1 ... number of items in the array
        else {
            throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest,
                           message: "blah blah")
            return }
let result = myArray[newIndex - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your particular case you can do something like:

```
func someFunction (index : Int?) throws {
    guard let newIndex = Optional( (index ?? 0) - 1 ), newIndex >= 0 else {
        throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest, message: "blah blah")
    }

    let result = myArray[newIndex]
    ....
}
```

- By `(index ?? 0)`, you are telling *if `index` isn't `nil` then `index = index!` otherwise 0*
- So you have your unwrapped value and you subtract 1 from it. But you have to use `Optional` type for *optional binding*. So make it optional by `Optional( (index ?? 0) - 1 )`
- By now, you've got your `newIndex` and by providing `newIndex >= 0` check you are confirming that you won't do anything with negative index values.

So you can convert ***1 based list index variable to 0 based array in a function***