# optional variable in class definition

Tags: swift, option-type

**optionals in class definition**

I have a 'mastermodel' from which most of my models inherit so they can have the configuration constants

```
class MasterModel {

    static let apiKey = (drop.config["app","thinx-api-key"]?.string)!
    static let baseURL = (drop.config["app","base-URL"]?.string )!

}
```

Notice the force unwraps :(
In this case it's not really a huge problem as the program won't start without these constants but I'd like to clean this up anyway.

guard statements are only allowed in functions, not in the class definition. What is the proper way to define those constants with error trapping

Comment: You're basically stuck doing it this way as long as you want to keep them static.  The alternative is to make them non-static computed properties and do whatever you want in the getter.

Comment: Forced unwrapping is not always evil. If the config paths `thinx-api-key` and `base-URL` are "hard-coded", just forced unwrap the optionals. In this case a missing key reveals a design error. Or add `assert` lines somewhere.

Comment: @vadian I agree. In this case using `?? ""` could be a possibility though.

Comment: @Sulthan No, use `!` and unwrap the optional. I'm quite concerned about the black-and-white suggestion *Never forced unwrap optionals, it's evil. Use always optional bindings*. There is a big difference between a potential runtime error and a design error. If you're going to access a file in the application bundle, use `!`, If you're going to cast a table view cell to a custom class, use `!`. If you retrieve a specific date component from a date, use `!`. In these cases a crash is *welcome* because it reveals a design error which must not happen.

Comment: @vadian I completely agree with you. I would also use `!` in this case. I am only suggesting `?? ""` as a potential alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign them with a computed closure to detect the configuration error

```
class MasterModel 
{

  static let apiKey:String  = { 
     if let result = drop.config["app","thinx-api-key"]?.string 
     { return result }
     print("MasterModel.apiKey error, missing app/thinx-api-key")
     return ""
  }()  // the () here makes the closure execute and return the value

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like your program to crash only if you actually use the property, you could use a computed/lazy one:

```
class MasterModel {

    static var apiKey: String {
        get {
            return drop.config["app","thinx-api-key"]?.string)!
        }
    }
    ...

}
```

This might be useful in case the static initialiser is called before `drop` has been successfully initialised.